# JS does not recognize the plugin of cordova

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, localnotification

I use `HTML5` and `PhoneGap`,

On application I have Local Notification.

Below is the code:

**[Local Notification](https://github.com/moumen-o/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification)**

The Android implementation for **local notification** uses a similar interface as the existing iOS **localnotification plugin.**  The plugin depends on the Android **AlarmManager** in combination with the ***Notification Bar***.

Here my js:

```
function appReady() {
    alert('Start appReady');
    var LN = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/LocalNotification");
    alert('LN');
    LN.add({
        date: new Date(2012, 10, 11, 15, 20, 0, 0),
        message: "DeviceReady",
        ticker: "This is a sample ticker text",
        repeatDaily: false,
        id: 1
    });
    alert('End appReady');
}
```

the alert 'LN' does not appear.

here my plugin in config.xml file:

```
<cordova>
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
    <access origin=".*"/>

    <log level="DEBUG"/>
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />

    <plugins>
       ...
      <plugin name="LocalNotification" value="org.apache.cordova.plugins.LocalNotification"/>
    </plugins>
</cordova>
```

It looks like the JS **does not know the plugin**, can anyone help?

Comment: No! I'm using version 2.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using navigator.notification.alert

This can be found in the [docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification)

Comment: This a normal alert, I want Notification even outside application in Notification Bar

Comment: maybe try this link http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/

You'll see that PhoneGap is listed under each of the iOS, Android and Blackberry sections.

Comment: I have tried this option, because I encountered a lot of problems I preferred to to switch to local notification ..

Comment: example what is Pushwoosh App ID?(appid)